# How to enable remote access to Master's proxy - "Failed connect to <ip>:8080; Connection refused"

Tags: proxy, kubernetes

I am playing with Kubernetes on https://labs.play-with-k8s.com.
I tried to use the `kubectl proxy` following the instructions in [Kubernete's website](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-kubernetes-api/http-proxy-access-api/#using-kubectl-to-start-a-proxy-server).
On the Master node (192.168.0.13) I ran: `kubectl proxy --port=8080`:

```
[node1 ~]$ kubectl proxy --port=8080
Starting to serve on 127.0.0.1:8080
```

On the Worker node I ran `curl -v http://192.168.0.13:8080` and it failed:

```
[node2 ~]$ curl -v http://192.168.0.13:8080
* About to connect() to 192.168.0.13 port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying 192.168.0.13...
* Connection refused
* Failed connect to 192.168.0.13:8080; Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed connect to 192.168.0.13:8080; Connection refused
```

Any idea why the connection is refused ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Starting to serve on 127.0.0.1:8080

As shown in the message it emits on startup, that is because `kubectl proxy` **only** listens on localhost (i.e. `127.0.0.1`), unless you instruct it otherwise:

```
kubectl proxy --address=0.0.0.0 --accept-hosts='.*'
```

and that `--accept-hosts` business is a regular expression for hosts (presumably `Referer` headers? DNS lookups?) from which `kubectl` will accept connections, and `.*` is a regex that matches every string including the empty ones.